# (Processing) How do I only display the final output of my loop when I run it?

Tags: loops, processing

```js
int i = 0;

float r;
float g;
float b;
float t;
float diametre;
float x;
float y;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  background(204);
  smooth();
  //noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  
  for (int i = 100; i > 701; i = i+1); {
  
  r = random (255);
  g = random (255);
  b = random (255);
  t = random (255);
  
  diametre = random (30);
  x = random (width);
  y = random (height);
  
  noStroke();
  fill(r,g,b,t);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  ellipse(x,y,diametre,diametre);
  
  if (mousePressed) {
    filter (INVERT);
  }
  }
}
```

Hi all, I'm a first year university student having a go at programming for the very first time.

Right now I'm stuck because when I run my code, it displays the circles one at a time for unlimited period of time.

But I'd like to set the code so that random 700 circles are made at the same time and shown... so that it becomes a static artwork.

How do I approach this problem and how would I change the current code?

Thanks

Comment: you are talking about a multi-threading if you want the circle to be drawn concurrently

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted works? `for (int i = 100; i > 701; i = i+1);` looks fishy.

Comment: Are you sure this is Java? The called functions look like JavaScript.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Yeah that's what I meant...

Comment: @bleistift2 yeah it still runs on Processing, but I tried to set the number of circles generated to be between 100 and 700, but not sure if I did it correctly

Comment: @Henry oh god im so stupid haha

Comment: multi threading + GUI at your level is too complicated and especially when debugging your code. Try some other project that outputs on console?

Comment: Have a look at [a for loop tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_for_loop.htm).

Comment: @Luminous_Dev  Right now when I run this code, it generates random circles one at a time continuously, I want my output to have 700 random circles generated at the same time (500 was a typo... sorry).. do I have to go through multi-threading + GUI?

Comment: YES, drawing circle is GUI already. Multithreading is needed if you want multiple circle to be drawn at the same time.

Comment: @JaehoChoi You cannot have 700 things (literally) happen at once. Your best choice is *hiding* the drawing process, i.e. make the canvas (or whatever it is you’re drawing on) invisible, draw the circles one after the other, then make the canvas visible again.

Comment: loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < 700; i++)`

Comment: @Luminous_Dev  Would there be a different approach to generating circles with random colors, coordinates and sizes at the same time?

Comment: @bleistift2 how would I make the canvas invisible...? I'm using Processor at the moment

Comment: is this java or javascript? im confused now

Comment: @Luminous_Dev The software I use is 'Processing' and it uses Java

Comment: @JaehoChoi No clue… To be honest, I thought “Processing” referred to image processing. I only learned that it is a technology after I posted that comment.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Why on earth would this require multithreading? Also, please see this: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: @bleistift2 Please see: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: Kevin Workman's answer is good. After you correct your loop, you might want to learn about PGraphics for offscreen buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 701; i = i+1); {
```

It's wrong for two reasons:

- You're starting `i` at `100` and looping as long as `i` is **greater than** `701`. This will never be true.
- You have a `;` semicolon at the end, which means even if this loop ever did evaluate to true, it doesn't actually contain any code.

To fix your problem, you need to fix your iteration and remove the `;` semicolon. If you want to loop 700 times, it would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 700; i = i+1) {
```

Then you can uncomment the call to `noLoop()` if you don't want it to be animated.